# azure webapp fails to start: Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. You > must install or update .NET to run this application

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core

I made serval changes in our api, one of them was upgrading to .net7. After deploying I get this error when the Azure Web App starts. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

> Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message: You
> must install or update .NET to run this application.

```
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.10' (x86)
.NET location: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\
```

I did select .NET 7 (STS)
[image]

If I downgrade to .net6 I got exactly the same error, except it can't find '6.0.21' (6.0.19 is installed) instead of '7.0.10'

```
The following frameworks were found:
  .......
  6.0.19 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  7.0.5 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  7.0.8 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

EDIT:
I 'solved' it by adding this step in my pipeline:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '7.0.305'
```

7.0.8 matches SDK 7.0.305 see: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error error recently and reason why was because even though my dotnet frameworks were installed on the machine, I was missing the dotnet runtimes for 7.0.

Installing the dotnet core runtime fixed it for me.

You can run the following command to see what runtimes are currently available on the machine running your web app :
`dotnet --list-runtimes`

you can download the dotnet core 7.0 runtime from here : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-7.0.10-windows-x64-installer

The above link is for windows x64, but if you have a different OS download the relevant runtime based on your OS or arch here : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would expect me to download a SDK on a Azure web app. You can select the .NET version for your webapp and I would say that would be sufficient to run my app

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I misunderstood your question earlier.

From what I understand, you have a running web app in azure portal and you have upgraded the app you deploy to it.

Just make sure the stack you have in your web apps -> configuration -> general settings tab is set to to the exact dotnet version you require.

Ex for dotnet 7.0 you need to set the following and save (which should restart your app) and then do a redeployment :

[image]

Comment: I did, just added a image, but I cannot select a Minor version like you, thats strange. Do you see the 7.0.10 version as a minor version?

Comment: no. I just see what I've shown in the image above. Weird that setting this option in General Settings doesnt not resolve your issue. Only other thing I can suggest is to recreate your Web app. Sorry I can't be of much help on this one. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it by adding usedotnet in my pipeline. I tried that before with version 7.0.8 but I had to use 7.0.305 with is the actual SDK version. Still weird that there is a mismatch between the latest SDK in the MSBuild in the pipeling and the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for this post!  We had a VERY similar issue and wasted a ton of time.  We contacted Azure support.  They couldn't help, but finally they sent us YOUR post.  We had similar issue with our runtimeconfig.json always having 6.0.0 but one day last week it changed to 6.0.25.  We still don't know why - no csproj or yml was changed.  Azure VM (windows-2022) didn't HAVE 6.0.25 so we had to look up the corresponding SDK version (which was 416) and specify THAT as the version like you showed above!

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
  packageType: 'sdk'
  version: '416'

We're still confused why the runtimeconfig.json changed versions without a yml or a csproj change.  Apparently something (maybe lack of specific version) caused it to 'ask for' 6.0.25 when Azure doesn't provide that one.  Definitely something that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I restarted the IIS solved the problem

Comment: The problem is related to Azure Web App deployment, not to hosting the web app on a local IIS.